# How to make animation not stutter and run forever?

Tags: html, css, animation

I have this animation which is supposed to run forever. But the observed result is some hiccing, stuttering that can be observed there (chrome) between repetitions. How to smooth it out without the effect of this stutter ?

```css
@-webkit-keyframes borderBlink {
  from,
  to {
    border-color: transparent
  }
  50% {
    border-color: black
  }
}

@keyframes borderBlink {
  from,
  to {
    border-color: transparent
  }
  50% {
    border-color: black
  }
}

.borderBlink {
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* add 'border-color: transparent' if you wish no border to show initially */
}

.borderBlink:hover {
  -webkit-animation: borderBlink 1s infinite;
  animation: borderBlink 1s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class='borderBlink'>Border flash on hover</div>
```

Comment: Runs smoothly here. Might be something on your PC, like background processes taking up too much CPU or GPU power.

Comment: No stuttering for me either.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest if you'd like a more smooth hover transition add the following in your **CSS** file -  `transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;` like so:

```
.borderBlink {
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  /* add 'border-color: transparent' if you wish no border to show initially */
}

.borderBlink:hover {
  -webkit-animation: borderBlink 1s infinite;
  animation: borderBlink 1s infinite;
}
```

This will provide a smooth `transition` on mouse over and mouse leave.